# How to troubleshoot the web.config runtime error in sharepoint 2010 environment?

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-config, .net, iis7, telerik

There are telerik control assembly entries in the config file.
How can I know root cause of this error?

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error 
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

Answer (score 1):

To get a more detailed error message directly in the browser, you can:

- Edit the web.config files located at `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\<port_number>` AND `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\` modify the parameters you have indicated in that web.config file:
  . `customErrors` mode must be `Off`
  . `CallStack` must be set to `true`
  More details at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/voyage/2014/09/02/enable-debugging-and-set-custom-errors-off-in-sharepoint/.
- Look at the SharePoint ULS logs.

Answer (score 0):

as its sharepoint 2010, look in the log file for any errors. It should be long when producing an error within the log files.

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\14\LOGS

make sure you open the latest text log file. Error should be close to the bottom.

in the web.config change:

```
<customErrors mode="On" />
```

to

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

and change:

```
<SafeMode … CallStack="false" … >
```

to

```
<SafeMode … CallStack="true" … >
```

finally change:

```
<compilation batch="false" debug="false">
```

to

```
<compilation batch="true" debug="true">
```